# Google script trigger does not activate part of the code

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this script, it works fine except for the part of the code where I should put the cursor on cell A2 when it is executed by a trigger, if I run it from the menu manually, all the code works fine.

But the "1 minute" trigger did not execute it. I would like to understand this error.

```
function Warehouse() {
  var s, data, ubcns, i, rw;
  s=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  ubcns=s.getDataRange().getValues();
  ubcns.shift();
  // los datos que hemos de distribuir
  data=ubcns.shift();
  //solamente la primera columna
  ubcns=ubcns.map(function(x) {return x[0];});
  //quita las filas antes de 10
  for (i in [3,4,5,6,7,8,9]) ubcns.shift();
  //fila de la ubicacion
  rw=ubcns.indexOf(data[0])+10;
  //poner datos
  s.getRange(rw, 2, 1, 15).setValues([data.slice(1)]);

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Scan');

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var cell = sheet.getRange('A2');
sheet.setCurrentCell(cell);
var selection = sheet.getSelection();
// Current cell: B5
var currentCell = selection.getCurrentCell();

  var rangesToClear = ['A2:C2'];
  for (var i=0; i<rangesToClear.length; i++) { 
    sheet.getRange(rangesToClear[i]).clearContent();




    }

}
```

This is the part of the code that does not execute the trigger, it does not give errors, it simply does not execute it.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var cell = sheet.getRange('A2');
sheet.setCurrentCell(cell);
var selection = sheet.getSelection();
// Current cell: B5
var currentCell = selection.getCurrentCell();
```

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: It works when I manually run it from the menu, but not when I set a 1 minute timer, did you set a timer?

Comment: Why do you need to activate that specific cell every minute? An onEdit() trigger would be a more optimized approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
function ttttt() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getRange('A2');
  sheet.setCurrentCell(cell);
  var selection = sheet.getSelection();
  var currentCell = selection.getCurrentCell();
  Logger.log(currentCell.getA1Notation());
  //A2
}
```

When you run it off of a timer the active Sheet is likely to be Spreadsheet.getSheets()[0];  I think it runs the code right off the server with no UI.

Comment: It works well executed manually, but not with the 1 minute trigger

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find that for a trigger, your 'SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();' may not necessarily be the sheet you intend it to be. Remember, a trigger is 'out there in the wild'. It will need to be told exactly what spreadsheet and what sheet is needs to access. Try using a sheet ID or better, openByID and getSheetByName methods.

Comment: I try this:


function mypos() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Scan");
    var cell = sheet.setActiveSelection("A2"); //getRange("A2");
    cell.activate();
    // La siguiente línea no se requiere.
    //SpreadsheetApp.flush(); 

}


It works fine manually, but the 1 minute trigger does not activate it...